# How would you rearrange a text file containing lists by the length of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example if i had a text file which contains:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
```

to:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Show us what you have try so far, please. We are here to help, not to do it for you.

Comment: read txt -> sort data -> write txt

Comment: Read the file into a `list` of lines, use `ast.literal_eval` to make the lines into `list`s then sort them based on `len`

Comment: Do you have only one of each size or multiples of the same size? That would make a difference in what you want to do. For example, can you have `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and `(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

Comment: I would have multiple files the same length, but it doesn't matter the order the lists of the same length are in

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 8, 2]]

sorted(data, key=lambda x : len(x))
```

Result with:

```
[[6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 8, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Even `key=lambda x: (len(x), x)`, so that lists of the same lists would sort lexicographically.

Comment: I think they do anyway. Part of the power of `sorted`.

Comment: I don't think so; if you provide `key`, only the list of key values is effectively sorted, and objects that generated the keys are rearranged accordingly. Usually a sorting algorithm does not rearrange equal items, so lists with equal length would retain their initial order. This can be easily tested: https://pastebin.com/Bn6TLTkZ